# PHP Cron Job with exec() function

Tags: php, cron, phantomjs

I am trying to program a Cron Job that fetches some data from multiple websites. The script uses `phantomjs` that runs a js file responsible for saving each website's content to a file locally.

My cron job command:

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/user/public_html/fetch.php >> /home/user/public_html/fetch-log.txt
```

**fetch.php**

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
require_once 'Utils.php';

$sources = Utils::get_sources();

foreach ($sources as $source) {
    $cmd = "/home/user/bin/phantomjs get-website.js '$source->url' $source->id";
    exec($cmd);
}

echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . ">> Done fetching sources\n";
```

**get-website.js**

```
var system = require('system');
var webPage = require('webpage');
var fs = require('fs');

var page = webPage.create();
var url = system.args[1];
var file = system.args[2];

var requestsArray = [];

page.onResourceRequested = function (requestData, networkRequest) {
    requestsArray.push(requestData.id);
};

page.onResourceReceived = function (response) {
    var index = requestsArray.indexOf(response.id);
    requestsArray.splice(index, 1);
};

page.open(url, function (status) {
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        if (requestsArray.length === 0) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            try {
                fs.write("/home/user/public_html/rss_contents/" + file + ".txt", page.content, 'w');
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
            phantom.exit();
        }
    }, 500);
});
```

The script works normally when running from browser, and the cron job also works normally when run with a simple `echo("done");` php script, but when I try to run the cron job with the `fetch.php` script, the last line is echoed to the file, but nothing has happen.

I am using shared hosting.

EDIT:
When trying to run `phantomjs` from ssh console directly, I get this error

> 2019-06-27T11:34:12 [WARNING] QThread::start: Thread creation error:
>   Resource temporarily unavailable

And the console just hangs without any response.
I couldn't find any posts talking about this warning on Google.

Comment: try debugging the cronjob version with `var_dump()`. I would start with a check if `$sources` has been filled after you set it. keep in mind that the CLI context might be configured in another way than the browser context. I'd also try this in a simple script `$cmd = "/home/user/bin/phantomjs get-website.js 'https://google.com' $source->id";
    exec($cmd);
}` to check if `exec()` is allowed.

Comment: @AlexOdenthal yes the `$sources` is not empty when looping and `exec()` is allowed as mentioned above, the script works normally when run from the browser.

Comment: run from the browser might be totally different than from console. which user runs the cronjob? access rights correct for the destination folder for the output file? is phantomjs itself working directly on the console?

Comment: @AlexOdenthal Honestly I don't know which user runs the cronjob. Can I specify it somewhere? And the right access to the destination folder are 0777. About the I edited my question to talk about the error I get when I run phantomjs directly on the console.

Comment: i found a github page which at least shows a connection between QT (QNetworkAccessManager) and Phantomjs. It seems that the amount of threads you are trying to open by your loop hits some limit. try if your code works with a fixes amount of loop runs like 3 times.

Comment: @AlexOdenthal I tried it with only one url from the `$sources`, didn't work either, the same error is showing

Comment: did you try to determine the availability and version opf phantomjs on the console? `/path/to/phantomjs/phantomjs -v`

Comment: @AlexOdenthal yes, it is indicating version 2.1.1

Comment: No more ideas - sorry.